How to deal with "supposing"?

Supposing you have done your assignment tomorrow, I will give you something for your effort - Correct or should it be

Supposing you have done your assignment by tomorrow, I will give you something for your effort



This has nothing to do with the use of supposing. The only difference is between tomorrow and by tomorrow, both of which are valid. PS Please use a spellchecker - your posts are full of typing errors!

@KateBunting I have seen that I can't do it with "if". "If you have done it tomorrow, I willl ..." wrong and it needs to be "If you have done it by tomorrow" Am i wrong ?

Or "If you do it tomorrow..."   "by tomorrow" is between now and then and "tomorrow" (without "by") excludes today.  The problem is the present perfect with a future-only adverb ("tomorrow").  The present perfect can't be used with time-phrases that exclude the present, such as "tomorrow" and "yesterday". "by tomorrow" includes the present.

I don't find supposing idiomatic in the cited context. I'd always expect if when the postulated future condition is effectively under the control of the addressee.

The only difference is "by" and this has its usual sense (q.v.)
In context, "will have done something tomorrow" and "will have done something by tomorrow" mean the same, with slight emphasis, meaning "in the time period leading to", added by the meaning of "by".  However that meaning is already implied without emphasis by the tense.
The word "supposing" doesn't change this analysis.  However I see no reason to use "supposing" if you are just linking cause and effect you would use the ordinary "first conditional":  If you've finished your homework (by) tomorrow, I'll give you something.

I have seen that I can't do it with "if". "If you have done it tomorrow, I willl ..." wrong and it needs to be "If you have done it by tomorrow" Am i wrong ?

Meh,  I'd probably want to use "finished"  rather than "done".
